# How to copy data from one table into another table which has a record repeated column in GCP Bigquery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am trying to copy data from one nested table into another nested table without flattening the data.

input_table : column1 STRING NULLABLE
column2 RECORD REPEATED
{
sub1 STRING NULLABLE
}

copy_table : column1 STRING NULLABLE
column2 RECORD REPEATED
{
sub STRING REPEATED
}

IF u see the sub1 column defination has been modified, in this case how do I copy the exact data without thr use of unnest.  because If I use unnest the rows increase as it flatten the record by row.

query :
insert into copy_table()
select column1,
[struct(array[column2.sub])]
from input_table,
unnest(column2) as column2;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your question,  **input_table** and **copy_table** would be like below

```sql
CREATE TEMP TABLE input_table AS
SELECT '111' column1, [STRUCT('aaa' AS sub1), STRUCT('bbb'), STRUCT('ccc')] AS column2;

CREATE TEMP TABLE copy_table (
  column1 STRING,
  column2 ARRAY<STRUCT<sub ARRAY<STRING>>>
);
```

Instead of **UNNEST**ing in **FROM** clause, you can transform **column2** at **SELECT list** clause using a subquery and insert it into your **copy_table**.

```sql
INSERT INTO copy_table
SELECT column1, ARRAY(SELECT AS STRUCT [sub1] AS sub FROM UNNEST(column2)) AS column2
  FROM input_table;
```

[image]
[image]